# error: Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\wamp\www\project\php\deleteRow.php on line 55

Tags: php

I got this error when trying to delete emails from a table form and database,,i tried to solved it but some fields work while others still gives me an error, any help is apreciated,,i am learning php on my own.

/*here is my code*/

```
<?php
 $dbhost = 'host';

 $dbuser = 'username';

 $dbpass = 'password';

 $dbname = 'databe_name';

 $dbtable = 'database_table';

 $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('Error connecting to mysql');
 //
 mysql_select_db($dbname,$conn) or die ("Could not open database");
 //
$sql="SELECT * FROM '$dbtable'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
?>
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td><form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<table width="400" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="4" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Delete multiple rows in mysql</strong> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">#</td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Id</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Sender</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Message</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Date</strong></td>
</tr>
<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>"></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows[0]; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows[2]; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows[3]; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows[4]; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
<tr>
<td colspan="5" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" value="Delete"></td>
</tr>
<?php
// Check if delete button active, start this
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
            $del_id = $_POST['checkbox'][$i]; /*this line gives me an error*/
            $sql = "DELETE FROM '$dbtable' WHERE id='$del_id'";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
    }
    // if successful redirect to delete_multiple.php
if($result){
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0' URL='deleteRow.php'>";
}
}
mysql_close();
?>
</table>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear: you're accessing an array index which doesn't exist. What line is line 55 in above code? I'd guess `$rows` is empty or doesn't have 5 elements.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
    $checkboxCount = count($_POST['checkbox']);
    for($i=0;$i<$checkboxCount;$i++){
            $del_id = $_POST['checkbox'][$i]; 
            $sql = "DELETE FROM '$dbtable' WHERE id='$del_id'";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
    }
    // if successful redirect to delete_multiple.php
if($result){
    echo "";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unchecked checkboxes do not have their value sent.

You probably need to replace your `for` body with:

```
if(isSet($_POST['checkbox'][$i])) {
        $del_id = $_POST['checkbox'][$i]; /*this line gives me an error*/
        $sql = "DELETE FROM '$dbtable' WHERE id='$del_id'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

checkbox post fields are only available in the post when checked. so your post array can contain only values 1 and 2. you loop through all your db rows change your $count variable in the count of the checkbox array

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST['checkbox'][1]` does not exist.

instead of using `$count` which is the number of query results in your code, use `count($_POST['checkbox'])`

So  `for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){` would become

```
 for($i=0; $i < count($_POST['checkbox']); $i++){
```

And on a second look, like others have suggested, not all indices of the checkbox may be set. It is better to use a `foreach` loop where you can get the key and value easily.

```
foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $key => $value){
```

Answer (score 0):

When a checkbox is not checked it won't show up in `$_POST['checkbox']`.

What you can do is to save all checked boxes in an array and after the loop execute a single delete query for all checked boxes.

```
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
    if (isset($_POST['checkbox'][$i])) $delids[] = $_POST['checkbox'][$i];
}

if (isset($delids) && is_array($delids)) {
    $sql = "DELETE FROM '$dbtable' WHERE id IN (".implode(',', $delids).")";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
}
```

But a better way would be to skip your `for`-loop and use `foreach` instead like this:

```
foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $c) {
    $delids[] = $c;
}

if (isset($delids) && is_array($delids)) {
    $sql = "DELETE FROM '$dbtable' WHERE id IN (".implode(',', $delids).")";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the confusion lies in the fact that you're using the value ($count - the number of rows) to index into the value for each checkbox.  The number of rows defines how many checkboxes there will be, but not the value of each checkbox.  Hence $i in the delete loop is not guaranteed to be less than the size of the checkbox array.